# Why does this loop doesn't execute in rc.local?

Tags: raspberry-pi

I want to use this loop in rc.local of my raspi to initialize some GPIO pins, but it doesn't execute. But when I run the code over ssh it just works.

```
for i in {4,17,27,22,5,6,13,26}; do 
    echo "$i" > /sys/class/gpio/export; 
    sleep 0.1; 
    echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio"$i"/direction;  
    echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio"$i"/value;
done;
```

also, this code still works in the rc.local:

```
echo 4 > /sys/class/gpio/export;
echo out > /sys/class/gpio/gpio4/direction;
echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio4/value;
```

Why would the loop not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brace expansion `{x,y,z,t}` is not a standard /bin/sh feature; it's an extension of bash/ksh/zsh.

However, in some Linux distributions, /bin/sh is actually the *ash* or *dash* shell – a faster, but more limited variant that only supports the "standard POSIX shell" features, but typically none of the bash-specific extensions.

This means that the loop only runs once, with the entire string "`{4,17,27,22,5,6,13,26}`" as the literal value of `$i`.

In your specific case, brace expansion is completely useless. You can just directly list the items:

```
for i in 4 17 27 22 2 6 13 26; do
```

In other cases, you could use e.g. 'seq' to replace {a..z}, or change the whole script to use `#!/bin/bash` (i.e. specifically call Bash) instead of /bin/sh.

Comment: Thank you! it works.